# Footer Separation

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/upvxrsaz/

I have made a simple footer but run into a problem with separation.

Is it possible to keep the "Copyright © 2015. All Rights Reserved | Privacy Policy" text on the left and the "Facebook, Twitter, Linkedin and Youtube" icons on the right with both still being on the same line?

I used multiple "break" tags to separate them but then it ran into problems when zooming in.

Every time I use "span" or "float" it moves them onto separate lines.

What I want is this

http://postimg.org/image/pd6r39g6b/

But without the "break" tags.

Many thanks

The HTML.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">[![enter image description here][1]][1]
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" dir="ltr" >
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="footer test.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="upper-footer">
</div>

<div id="footer-outer">
<div id="footer-inner">

Copyright &copy; 2015. All Rights Reserved | <a href="" title="">Privacy Policy</a><a href="" title=""><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" title=""><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" title=""><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" title=""><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-2x"></i></a>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS.

```
    /*------------------Body------------------*/
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

/*------------------Upper Footer------------------*/
#upper-footer{
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}

/*------------------Footer------------------*/
#footer-inner{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}

#footer-inner a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#ffffff;
}

#footer-inner a:link{
    color:#ffffff;
}

#footer-inner a:hover{
    color: #FF0000;
}

#footer-inner a:active{
   color: #FFFF00;
}

/*------------------Footer Outer------------------*/
#footer-outer { 
     background: #000000;
}
```

Comment: can you define clearly what do you want

Comment: I want to put the Copyright text on the left and the social media text on the right but on the same line.

Comment: Can you post an image of what you're trying to achieve? Do you want to center both spans vertically? Also, what do you mean by "expand with text"?  Post the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you mean? - https://jsfiddle.net/hedgehog34/1pekqp0g/4/

**CSS:**

```
/*------------------Body------------------*/
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

/*------------------Upper Footer------------------*/
#upper-footer{
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}

/*------------------Footer------------------*/
#footer-inner{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:5px 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    clear: both;
}

#footer-inner a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#ffffff;
}

#footer-inner a:link{
    color:#ffffff;
}

#footer-inner a:hover{
    color: #FF0000;
}

#footer-inner a:active{
   color: #FFFF00;
}

/*------------------Footer Outer------------------*/
#footer-outer { 
     background: #000000;
}
span:first-child {
    margin-top:12px;
}
```

I can't answer your last two questions, as you'll need to clarify them. Question no.2 is not very welcome on Stack Overflow, as it is site dedicated specifically for technical problems, while term "better" seems to be very subjective.

Comment: I see, I am still very new to this so I am still learning the ropes. Thanks for getting back to me on this.

Yes that is what I mean and that is what I tried. However they are now on separate lines now. You can tell that they are because if you float the "Social Media Icons" left they don't line up.

Comment: I assumed that you might want to vertically center them, but it seems like you're for something else. Do you want them to be both aligned to the baseline (bottom)? Is your image showing desired output, or a problem?

Comment: The image is the problem. I just want to two sets of text to be on either side of the page, I will center them later, for now I really just want them to be on the same line, none of the solutions work and people are getting upset with the post for some reason.

Comment: What confuses me in your question, is "them to be on the same line" part -  Can you mockup desired output - this would be the best way, to see what you're after.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/pd6r39g6b/

this is what I'm after

Comment: Since you're not dealing with `inline` elements, after you used `float` property, you cannot use `vertical-align`, which is doing what you want to do, but only to `inline` type of elements. Ie. `vertical-align:baseline`. Instead you can use `margin-top` on your first element and manually set it up, which will push it down to desired level - https://jsfiddle.net/hedgehog34/1pekqp0g/4/. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what this is supposed to look like but I would not be using spans here, especially as you are floating them.

By adding floats you make them block level elements so I'd prefer to use a div.

I also prefer (opinions differ) not to have bare text nodes so I wrapped the copyright text etc in a paragraph.

Finally, don't use non-breaking spaces for spacing, that's not what they are for. Use margins/padding instead.

```css
/*------------------Body------------------*/
 body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
/*------------------Upper Footer------------------*/
 #upper-footer {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
/*------------------Footer------------------*/
 #footer-inner {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:5px 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    clear: both;
}
#footer-inner a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#ffffff;
}
#footer-inner a:link {
    color:#ffffff;
}
#footer-inner a:hover {
    color: #FF0000;
}
#footer-inner a:active {
    color: #FFFF00;
}
/*------------------Footer Outer------------------*/
 #footer-outer {
    background: #000000;
}
.legal, .social {
    line-height: 30px;
 }

.legal {
    float: left;
}
.legal p {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: .5em;
}

.social a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.social {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
    <div id="upper-footer"></div>
    <div id="footer-outer">
        <div id="footer-inner">
            <div class="legal">
                <p>Copyright &copy; 2015. All Rights Reserved | <a href="" title="">Privacy Policy</a>
                </p>
            </div>
                <div class="social"> <a href="" title=""><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
 <a href="" title=""><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
 <a href="" title=""><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i></a
     <a href="" title=""><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-2x"></i></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Other than that the rest of your question(s) is really not suitabale for SO

Comment: I am new to this so I'm still learning :)